# Autoresize Element (div) to Fit Horizontal Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried googling, but didn't come up with much. I'm building a horizontal carousel which displays images in a LI, floated. The issue I want to solve is, everytime I add thumbnails to the carousel (I'm lazy loading), I need to recalculate the width of the carousel (so that all the floated thumbnails line up nicely side by side).

For one, I rather not have to do these kinds of calculations in JS, and for two, I found that it's hard to find a cross browser way to ensure that the width will be properly calculated (I end up having to add or remove pixels from the total width depending on the browser).

So my question is, is there any way without JS, to be able to add content to a div, and have the width adjust as needed, the same way a div's height would?

And if not, have you found a more efficient way to handle this scenario than recalculating the width every time?

I'm not new to web dev, and for as long as I've been in this field, to my knowledge this has never been possible. But with the advent of new technologies cropping up, I thought maybe there was an obscure way of achieving this now.

Thanks in advance!

**[EDIT] (for clarification, but simplified):** If my carousel is 500px wide with overflow hidden. There's a slideable section containing thumbnails, each is 100px wide, floated, they fit 5 across in the carousel. When a user clicks Next, it lazy loads the next set of 5 thumbnails, and appends it to the slider area after the first set of 5. But since this div was 500px wide to accommodate 5 thumbnails, adding another 5, I need to recalculate the width to get the new thumbnails to show up side by side. Ideally I'd like to find a way to have the div autoresize its width to fit horizontal content, the same way it naturally does for vertical content.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking for. It would help if you could create a little example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or if you drew a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that using a containing carousel div with `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` has worked. I then have `display: inline-block` for each item in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Using this class for each individual item:

```
.eachItem {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Will work (I've done something similar to that).

The problem is that in IE7 it won't work! and you'll have to use JavaScript anyway :(

EDIT: I meant inline-block... and as you may know, IE7 doesn't "like" it.

Comment: Does that actually work? I did a quick test, but it's definitely not making the parent div wider based on its content (actually it treats it like display block). I thought inline-block treated the element like a block level element (padding and dimensions apply), but it stays inline with the rest of the content like a span does, but not necessarily making the parent wider (if a span contains a reallllllllly long word, and goes up against the edge of a div, it drops below to a new line, rather than make the parent wider)

Comment: After reading your edit, what comes to my mind is to have a front div that fits the screens width and inside have a massive width div that holds the thumbs, that way it will work, and possibly you could "navigate" through the thumbs with somekind of arrows?, could you show some code?

Comment: reply to comment #1: depends on the rest of your styles... I'm not sure what's going on there, but from what I gather, your div isn't wide enough (hence the resize), so you could try my second suggestion.

Comment: Can't show code as it's client related. But I am doing exactly what you mentioned in your first comment, there's a "front div" that acts as a viewport, and an inner div containing the thumbnails. This inner div gets resized with JS every time I add more thumbnails to it

Comment: why resize the inner div? just make it extra wide (like 9000px) and all works well (except for IE7...)

Comment: Well because I'm never going to be sure how many thumbnails can possibly be in there. It could be as high as 200 or more. I don't quite have the liberty to put a cap limit on it, or to assume it'll NEVER be more than a certain amount.

Comment: IE7 it will work....if you do it right. `display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;`