# Expanding a parent div "row-fluid" horizontally to fit its floated children using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Many issues have been raised in the same context. However , this ticket is for Bootstrap Framework.

Indeed, i do want to make all Panels in the same line . Thus, the Container Div (row-fluid style class) should be .

## [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/wb5es0zc/)

I make an attempt . But, as you note , panels are not in the same line

[image]

Basing on [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5357643/747579) , i add [this Css](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/wb5es0zc/1/) :

```
.ui-level{

      white-space: nowrap!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    
}
.myitem{
    
         display: inline-block!important;
}
```

However , no good news. :(

Comment: Do you really want ALL the 14 panels to be in the same line or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: really , i am not joking . thank u

Comment: Have you tried with the answer's solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
.ui-level{
 display:inline-block;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/isqware/wb5es0zc/2/

Comment: same line not same column. Thank u anyway,however , be careful of vote-down .

Comment: Opps, sorry about that. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: May I ask, did you find the solution for your answer?

Comment: Check the above link if thats what you are tring to do

Comment: you can develop it further to make it behave differently on mobile and tablet devices

Answer (score 0):

The default max columns for boostrap are 12. If you want 14 you have to change the default value. You can do it in the [bootstrap customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)  changing the @grid-columns parameter and download the modified source.

Related to the code [try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rewobs/wb5es0zc/11/) that I've edited. It works but you should improve the performance(of the .clone().first() ).

If you want 14 columns just use `col-md-1` so each panel use 1/14 of the grid.